# Algorithm to determine proper html tag closing

Tags: java, html, algorithm, parsing, tags

I'm writing my own implementation of an HTML parser in JAVA.
I have done lexer so far and proceeded to coding parser. I'm creating DOM tree and I would like to determine if my HTML is properly constructed.

E.g., I have a ***img*** tag which is a ***void*** tag based on [w3 org html syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element)

and it does not need end tag.

On the other hand, most of the tags like ***body***, **head** must have its end tag.

My question is: what is the proper way to handle this ?

I don't need a tool or any external site for determing, I'm asking what is the way to determine.

Comment: I might not be an HTML expert, but isn't there a limitied amout of **void** elements with reserved keywoards? http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/html5/void-elements-html5/

Comment: @AndrewMcCoist there is, so probably a List with exceptions will do.

Comment: You'd have to know which tags are `void`, so you need an explicit list. Also note that some tags (e.g. [`<p>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/p.html#p)) have *optional* end tags. Fun, fun!

Comment: `<td>` and `<tr>` are more exceptions

Comment: nough said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're dealing with HTML, so the set of tags is pretty much limited. You can easily keep track if a tag is a **void** tag or not.

For the rest of the tags, I suggest the following algorithm:

1. Get the next tag. 
   (a) If it is an opening tag, for example *<body>*, simply push it to the Stack. 
   (b) If it is a closing tag, go to step 2. 
   (c) If there are no more tags left to parse, your HTML is valid.
2. Pop tags from the Stack one-by-one. 
   (a) If you encounter another *opening tag* on the stack before reaching the opening pair of your current tag, then your HTML structure is corrupt.
   (b) If you empty the stack and there still isn't a pair to your current *closing tag*, then again, your HTML is corrupt.
   (c) If you encounter the *opening pair* of your current tag avoiding cases (a) and (b). Go to step 1.

This is a rough pseudo-code, but I hope you get the idea. I can write an implementation in Java/C# if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic "job interview problem" in many software companies. It is about checking whether a String (in this case, your HTML code) is balanced with respect to some characters (in this case, HTML tags). This problem is solved using a Stack. When you are processing the String, for each opening tag, you invoke a "push" operation. For each closing tag, you invoke a "pop" operation. Your HTML code will be balanced if the Stack is empty at the end of the processing (and no error is found during the analysis). The function below checks whether a String is balanced in terms of parentheses.

```
private boolean isBalanced(String s) {

    Stack symbolStack = new Stack();

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { //Processing the input string ...

        char c = s.charAt(i);

        if(c == '(') { //If the character is an opening parenthesis --> push

            symbolStack.push(c);
        }
        else if(c == ')') { //If the character is a closing parenthesis ...

            if(symbolStack.isEmpty()) { //Error: the stack is empty
                return false;
            }
            else {
                char c2 = (char) symbolStack.pop();

                if(c2 != '(') { //Error: no opening parenthesis in the stack
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(symbolStack.isEmpty()) { //No error and empty stack --> balanced string
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```